# Displaying SQL query Results and Editing the content Error

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have written code for displaying content of a sql query on a webpage in aspx, I need to edit the column names of the returned result on the webpage. Below is the code for displaying content

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace XYZ
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABC"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    string queryString = "select * from asde";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString,con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    SqlDataReader reader;
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    GridView1.DataSource = reader;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any pointers in editing the column names is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the datareader as the grid data source. Also data adapter should initialize with the sql command associated.

You can do something like below

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from asde", con); 
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapater(cmd);
   da.Fill(dt);
   GridView1.DataSource = dt;
   GridView1.DataBind();


 or 

  SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Load(dr);
  GridView1.DataSource = dt;
  GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: `Error 1 The type or namespace name 'SqlDataAdapater' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
This is the error I am facing

Comment: @user3088731: I think you using the name correctly `SqlDataAdapter`? also try referencing `System.Data.DataTable`

Comment: Resolved the issue but my goal is to edit the column header names isnt solved yet :(

Comment: I am fetching the data on to the webpage now I need to edit the column header name

Comment: @user3088731: Question is not clear! You mean to edit the data or table column header? or display custom column name?

Comment: Edit the table column header

Comment: @user3088731: Use grid afteredit event and alter the table based on table and column!